# How old was Sarai when she was in Egypt?

Tags: genesis

Genesis 12:11 As he was about to enter Egypt, he said to his wife Sarai, “Look, I know that you are a beautiful woman, 12and when the Egyptians see you, they will say, ‘This is his wife.’ Then they will kill me but will let you live. 13Please say you are my sister, so that I will be treated well for your sake, and on account of you my life will be spared.”

14So when Abram entered Egypt, the Egyptians saw that the woman was very beautiful.

How could she be so beautiful when she was so old?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, Sarah was ten years younger than Abraham (See Gen 17).

Next, Abram was 75 years old when they left Haran (Gen 12:4) so Sarai was 65 years old.  It appears that the incident in Gen 12:11 occurred soon after.  In any case it was well before the incidents with Lot (Gen 13, 14) and well before the birth of Ishmael (Gen 16) when Abram was 86 years old and Sarai 76.

The stunning beauty of Sarai was not only noticed by Pharaoh in Gen 12 but also turned the head of Abimelek in Gen 20 when Sarah was even older.

I have no difficulty with Sarah remaining very beautiful into her seventies and even eighties; she died at the age of 127 (Gen 23:1) - much older than people live today.

I did a quick internet search and found many older women in the sixties, seventies and eighties who were still very beautiful.  So, I see no problem for Sarah to have remained attractive at these ages.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Dottard above with the dates are helpful. In Genesis 12 Sarai is approximately 65 years old, and in Genesis 20 she is now +76 years old.

However, I don't agree that it's simply that she remained physically beautiful. There is no particular indication in the text of her physical beauty.

Rather the Apostle Peter suggests that her beauty was an inner beauty: "the imperishable beauty of a gentle and quiet spirit... for this is how the holy women who hoped in God used to adorn themselves... as Sarah obeyed Abraham..." (1 Peter 3:5-6).

I think Peter is helping us see back in the Genesis narrative that Sarai/Sarah's beauty was inner which overflowed in her outward actions and personality.

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics.SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803).